# Timer for DateTime on a label , error

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

i wanted to update my `DateTime` label every second.. i have this code.. but i get an error.. says `" Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'int' "`

This is my code... can someone tell me how should i fix this?

```
private void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }



private void User_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
            myTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            myTimer.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.interval%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property wants a numeric value (milliseconds) not a TimeSpan

```
 myTimer.Interval = 1000;
```

Keep in mind, however, that triggering an event every second just to update a clock label is probably a bit excessive. The same MS updates the clock on the tray bar every minute. I am pretty sure that if you put your machine under an heavy workload you will notice jumps on the label updates.

Answer (score 2):

Interval accepts milliseconds as double not a TimeSpan
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timers.timer.interval%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

From MSDN

```
[TimersDescriptionAttribute("TimerInterval")]
[SettingsBindableAttribute(true)]
public double Interval { get; set; }
```

Comment: so what should i replace the timespan?

Comment: 1 second = 1000 ms =>  myTimer.Interval = 1000;

Answer (score 2):

```
myTimer.Interval = 1000;//miliseconds
```